# How to derive this version of variance formula

Tags: self-study, computational-statistics

A probably very easy computational question, but I don't really understand how it's done:

I try to compute the point estimates of a normal distribution as $N \sim (\beta, \sigma)$. Using the method of moments, we get:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} = \hat{\beta}$$

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{2} = \hat{\sigma}^2 + \hat{\beta}^2$$

Solving the two equations for the two parameters, we get:

$$\hat{\beta} = \overline{X} $$

and

$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i} - \overline{X}_n)^2 $$

My question is: How do we get to the term of $\hat{\sigma}^2$? If I try to compute it, I get:

$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^2 - (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} )^2 $$

Can someone show me how to simplify the last term to what is stated above and what "rule" or law" is used there? Since it is used so often, I really wanna understand this.

Comment: I was certain this had been answered several times already but I can't seem to turn one up in spite of trying a host of searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2  
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( X_i^2 - 2 X_i \overline{X} + \overline{X}^2 \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2   -2 \overline{X}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i  + \sum_{i=1}^n \overline{X}^2  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2   -2 \overline{X}(n \overline{X}) + n \overline{X}^2  \\
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \right) - n \overline{X}^2
\end{align*}
Then you have $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2  = \frac{1}{n} \left( \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \right) - n \overline{X}^2\right) = \frac{1}{n}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \right)- \overline{X}^2$.

Comment: Great!! Wasn't aware of the sum to average shift - super obvious but simply didn't see it. Thank you so much!